# Why does model.fit() function give error?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I generated embedding matrix from BERT embeddings as below:

```
# Load pre-trained model tokenizer and model
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')

# Define batch size
batch_size = 1

# Tokenize and encode input data in batches
encoded_inputs = []
for i in range(0, len(labeled_data), batch_size):
    inputs = labeled_data[i:i+batch_size]
    encoded_inputs.append(tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(inputs, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt"))

# Generate embeddings for each batch
embeddings_new = []
for encoded_input in tqdm(encoded_inputs):
    with torch.no_grad():
        model_output = model(**encoded_input)
    batch_embeddings = model_output.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1)
    embeddings_new.append(batch_embeddings)

embeddings_new = tf.concat(embeddings_new, axis=0) 
embedding_matrix = model.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight
embedding_matrix = embedding_matrix.cpu().detach().numpy()
embed_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(embedding_matrix, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then using this matrix as initial weights to an LSTM:

```
lstm_out1 = 150
embed_dim = 768
   
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], embed_dim, weights=[embed_tensor], input_length=50, trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out1, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))

model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=adam,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Now when I call model.fit it produces error.

```
model.fit(tokenized_sentences, labels, batch_size=5, epochs=1, shuffle=True)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

The content of tokenized_sentences is a list:

```
[[101, 10406, 10161, 170, 10350, 87881, 10113, 21681, 11460, 13080, 10114, 10380, 10201, 10113, 108850, 10138, 12718, 10112, 10126, 15694, 10269, 62137, 13173, 10483, 102].....]
```

The content of the labels is also a list:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

The embed_tensor is like below:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.02595074 -0.00617341 -0.00409975 ...  0.02965234  0.02417551
   0.01970279]
 [ 0.01038065 -0.0136286   0.00672081 ...  0.01237162  0.0267217
   0.03370738]
 [ 0.0220679  -0.00360613  0.01932366 ...  0.0069061   0.026809
   0.00498276]
 ...
 [ 0.00684139  0.01885802  0.02666426 ...  0.02292391  0.06465269
   0.04373793]
 [ 0.0183579   0.01480132  0.02434449 ...  0.03205629  0.00708906
   0.02039703]
 [ 0.02139908  0.01879423 -0.01343376 ... -0.00597953  0.00583893
  -0.00586251]], shape=(119547, 768), dtype=float32)
```

Code for generating tokenized_sentences:

```
tokenized_sentences = []
for sentence in labeled_data:
    # Apply the tokenizer to each sentence to obtain its tokens
    tokens = tokenizer.encode(sentence, add_special_tokens=True)
    # Append the tokenized sentence to the list
    tokenized_sentences.append(tokens)
```

Why does model.fit() give error?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can see for the other inputs you specifically cast them to TF Tensors, you can also forcefully try to cast the labels to:

```
labels = np.array(labels).astype('float32')
```

or

```
labels = tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: Generating a new error: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'int\'>"})'}), <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

Comment: What if you use labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.float32)

Comment: Same error. Shouldn't we convert the tokenized_sentences too? It's just a list of lists.

Comment: We should indeed. I was wondering, given here : https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter2/6?fw=tf, # Returns TensorFlow tensors
tokenized_sentences= tokenizer(sequences, padding=True, return_tensors="tf"), it should be normal, but can you also add the code for tokenized_sentences, I don't see it anywhere

Comment: Code provided....................

Comment: Yes, so could you use return_tensors ="tf" and also tf.convert_to_tensor() on the tokenized_sentences

Comment: error during tokenization--->InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [1,25] != values[1].shape = [1,39] [Op:Pack] name: packed

Comment: I think in this case you have to use padding, because there are sentences of different lengths (see 25,39) and tf.pack() operation fails in TensorFlow. Could you add padding="True", truncation="True" in  tokenizer.encode(sentence, add_special_tokens=True)?

Comment: model.fit --->ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
  y sizes: 50
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.